# Check if string's value is higher or lower than another string in php

Tags: php, arrays, post

I'm trying to take two strings and print them out in alphabetical order.  For example, I am taking their first and last name.  If first name <= last name (ex. adam apple), then print out "First name = Adam Last name = Apple" else print out Last name = whatever the last name is, and first name = whatever the first name is.  It's coming from Post data, here is my code.

```
if (isset($_POST["name"])){
    $fullname=$_POST["name"];
    if (!empty($fullname)){
        $fullnameArray = explode(" ", $fullname);
        if ($fullnameArray[0] <= $fullnameArray[1]){
            echo "First name: " . $fullnameArray[0];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "Last Name: " . $fullnameArray[1];
        }else{
            echo "Last name: " . $fullnameArray[1];
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "First Name: " . $fullnameArray[0];
        }
        echo "<br/>";
        }else{
            echo "Please enter your first and last name.";
            echo "<br/>";
        }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

Comment: So does **Apple Adam** return **'Firstname:Adam'** and **'Lastname:Apple'**?

Comment: That's what I want, but with spaces of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `if (strcmp($fullnameArray[0], $fullnameArray[1]) < 0)`.

See [the PHP.net description of strcmp](http://php.net/strcmp). If you care about mixed case, you may want `strcasecmp` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter but less readable version.

```
$fullnameArray = explode(' ', $fullname, 2);
$ordered = strcasecmp($fullnameArray[0], $fullnameArray[1]) < 0;
$fullnameArray[0] = ($ordered ? 'First' : 'Last') . ' name: ' . $fullnameArray[0];
$fullnameArray[1] = ($ordered ? 'Last' : 'First') . ' name: ' . $fullnameArray[1];
echo implode("\n<br/>", $fullnameArray) . "\n<br/>\n";
```

Comment: What if someone were to enter more than two words, for example John Jay Ramon, how do you fix that error?

Comment: How would you know which one is the name and which one is the surname in a 2-word input at first place?